# iPad UITableView flickering issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a `UITableView` that contain about 20 rows in the iPad's viewport. I have a interval timer that will call `UITableView's` `reloadData` regularly(post it to UI thread).

Now when I scroll through the `UITableView` with medium speed (not so fast), that `UITableView` will refresh with flickering effect.

I have to write a function to manually update the `UITableViewCell` label by looping through all the items in the array (this array keep all the items that show on `UITableView`). I will execute this function when timer is running instead of calling `reloadData` (as I mentioned above). Then the flickering issue is gone.

I believe that reloadData should be better than looping through all the data because reloadData will only refresh the current showing Cells instead of all the rows, but I couldn't figure out why the flickering happens. Anyone know why?

One thing I have to mention is I did use the `CellIdentifier` correctly to reuse the cell and only create the cell when the retrieved cell is null.

Moreover, I do not have this issue in iPhone and I believe that it is because iPhone has lesser row compare to iPad.

Anyone can give some explanation about this issue?

Comment: have you try with `[tblMsgConverstion beginUpdates];[tblMsgConverstion endUpdates];`?

Comment: @NitinGohel hi, do you mind to elaborate how to do that? put reloadData between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with flickering when using `reloadData`. I solved it by using `indexPathsForVisibleRows` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to only update the visible cells. Performance is good since I don't have to iterate over the whole data set, but only a limited number of visible cells.

Answer (score 0):

`reloadData` causes the tableview to recreate the visible cells on screen which can result in a flickering since the cells get destroyed. There are better ways to reload the tableview. Are you using Core Data? If so the [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and it's [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate) are a great way to update a tableview since it listens to changes in the underlying datasource and only updates the appropriate cells.